# "YouTube said: Unable to extract video data" while downloading youtube data

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

I am trying to youtube-dl to get metadata information of some videos. It was working fine till dec 2020. Recently It started giving me this error "YouTube said: Unable to extract video data".
What did i try?

1. Update to latest youtube-dl: I did this everyday till dec 28
2. I tried using command line and python library
3. I used the option to remove cache directory (--rm-cache-dir)
4. Use different VPNs and try downloading it.

`youtube-dl https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hT_nvWreIhg --skip-download --rm-cache-dir` 
They blocked it after i downloaded info for ~30k videos.
Can anyone tell me how youtube is detecting my machine and if there is a way to bypass it using youtube-dl

Comment: Maybe try all this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63816790/youtube-dl-error-youtube-said-unable-to-extract-video-data

Answer (score 0):

Suddenly after few days reinstalling the youtube-dl library fixed this issue.