# Why has youtube-dl started giving this error message - YouTube said: Unable to extract video data

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

I use to download EAC videos for testing using this command line -

```
youtube-dl -f bestvideo[ext=mp4] --user-agent '' <youtube_url>
```

But now when I am running it, it gives an error message saying -

```
YouTube said: Unable to extract video data
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Your question should already be answered in this thread:
[Youtube_dl : ERROR : YouTube said: Unable to extract video data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63816790/youtube-dl-error-youtube-said-unable-to-extract-video-data)

Basicaly use the same user agent and cookie as your browser.

Best regards

Comment: Thanks mate. I upgraded youtube-dl using 

brew upgrade youtube-dl

and it seems to be working

Answer (score 1):

I ran this command to upgrade my youtube-dl

brew upgrade youtube-dl

After upgrading, the problems seems to have gone away. But I will check this extensively by checking it on multiple videos and see if it got resolved completely or only for few videos